# Angle between edge and lateral face of a regular pyramid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**MABCD** is a regular pyramid (**ABCD** is square and the lateral edges are equal). The angle between the base **ABCD** and the plane through **BD**, which is perpendicular to **MC**, is $\phi$. Then what is the sine of the angle between **MB** and  the plane **MAD**.

I have found it to be $sin2\phi\over \sqrt{1+cos^2\phi} $, but using very tedious approach involving a lot of calculations. (expressing all the edges with $\phi$ and the lateral edge, translating **MB** and applying the triangle similarity principles, the Pythagorean and Cosine Theorems a few times).

Is my answer correct and is there an easier approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done a lot easier using altitudes and volumes.